# .htaccess Joomla 3 not redirecting 301 non-sef

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I used Joomla 3.1 for a redesign of a Joomla 1.5 site and had to redirect a lot of url's due to a new menu structure.

I have created redirects 301 in my .htaccess file but it only redirects the SEF URLs - how come or what am I doing wrong...

It does redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /about-us/sailing-team/16-company.html http://www.endeavoursailing.co.uk/about-us/sailing-team.html
```

It does not redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /?format=html&tmpl=component&phocadownload=1&catid=0&id=41 http://www.endeavoursailing.co.uk/impressions/photo-gallery.html
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The redicts are done on the URL that is called, not on your internal URL (unless you call it), search the web about redirect rules, there are plenty of tutorials and documents available to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks but Google Webmaster tools showed me those URL's so it is called or do I understant you wrong. Another example found is: /?start=4 and if I put htis in my htaccess as: Redirect 301 /?start=4 http://www.mydomain.co.uk/ it does not redirect it only redirects SEF URL's but not the non sef... if you could give me hint what I have to look for it would be nice - as I have been searching google for the last days but have not idea what to look for and why it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common problem with redirecting GET requests is that **the order** of the parameters does not matter to the request itself, but it does matter to the redirect comparison. So, for Joomla!, the parameters

```
format=html&tmpl=component
```

and

```
tmpl=component&format=html
```

are equivalent, but for the .htaccess redirection, they are different.

Another thing is that your URL contains `catid=0` - but most likely there is no such category, since ids are *positive* integers.

Comment: Thanks but I dont understand what you mean - why can I redirect sef links only but not non sef

Yes there is no such category and the old url does not exist anymore so I wanted to redirect it to a similar page on the new site - but the same happesn with all non sef url's found by google I cannot redirect them another example is: Redirect 301 /?start=4 http://www.mydomain.co.uk it does not redirect but simply goes to ttp://www.mydomain.co.uk/?start=4

Answer (score 0):

With mod_rewrite enabled add pairs of "cond, rule" to your .htaccess file e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content\&view=category\&layout=blog\&id=10\&Itemid=4$
RewriteRule index.php  /pageOne? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_query_string_$
RewriteRule index.php  /pageTwo? [R=301,L]
```

The first example will redirect:
/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&...
to: /pageOne 
The "?" in "/pageOne?" removes query parameters.

The characters that must be escaped are: ". \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -" 
read more at: [php escape special chars in regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)